# Django: Get last record by ID [many-to-one relationship]

Tags: django, database, django-models, orm, python-3.7

I'm trying to get the last record in one table connected to another one using many-to-one relationship in django models. Here's my django models:

```
class DataCollecttion(models.Model):
    default_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class NameHistory(models.Model):
    old_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collection_data = models.ForeignKey(DataCollection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Here I created a sample data for `DataCollection` table:

[image]

And here's the sample data for `NameHistory` table:

[image]

What I want here is to filter or get the last record in `NameHistory` in each `collection_data_id` (the records inside the red rectangle) and display it in my views. 
So in short I want to get these lines and how can I do it in ORM Query:

```
sample3
test2
data1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a [window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions):

> **Window functions** provide a way to apply functions on partitions. Unlike a normal aggregation function which computes a final result for each set defined by the group by, window functions operate on frames and partitions, and compute the result for each row.

For your schema design:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions.window import FirstValue

( DataCollecttion
  .objects
  .annotate(
     first_old_name=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('namehistory__old_name'),
        partition_by=[F('id'), ],
        order_by=F('namehistory__id').desc()
     )
   )
  .values_list('first_old_name', flat=True)
  .distinct()
 )
```

This should return the expected list.

Comment: `expression=FirstValue('old_name')` in this part, the `old_name` is from `NameHistory`. .

Comment: i think your answer so far is the closest one. i'm still configuring it but i think is answers my problem. .

Comment: hello sir! How can I display these data to my template? Im using jinja templating. .

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
from django.db.models import Max
NameHistory.objects.values('old_name').annotate(Max('id'))
```

It will return the largest id (latest) of the NameHistory Table.

Comment: I tried this one, but it returns me a queryset. how can I only get the data of `old_name`?. .

Comment: @N.Omugs Try this, NameHistory.objects.values('old_name').annotate(Max('id')).values_list('old_name', flat=True). This will return list of `old_name`
You could also, iterate over the queryset with a for loop to display the names
[i['old_name'] for i in NameHistory.objects.values('old_name').annotate(Max('id'))]