# Django join multiple models in query result

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to do an equivalent of a **LEFT JOIN** using *django models*? Let's assume that I have 3 models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookmarked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# in my DRF view, I want to return:
# [
#  {
#   "id": post.pk, 
#   "owner": post.owner,
#   "title": post.title,
#   "bookmark_id": bookmark.id, //  should be null if current user has not bookmarked the post
#   "comment_count": total_number_of_comments for this post
#  }, 
# ...]

class PostView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
```

I want to return all post, but also include the bookmark id of the post which current user has bookmarked. I am currently using 2 LEFT JOINS to achieve this but I am wondering if there is a django way of getting the same output.

Comment: Can you add your serializers? and also what is the current json response?

Comment: Easy way is to make two queries and do the join on memory (on application and not on database) The hard way is to use [window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58909937/842935) If this app has not a thousand of requests by minute just make two queries. If it has thousand of requests by minute move to a cache schema.